# Page size changing when printing

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I have a button added to our web page which when clicked executes the following ready for printing.

```
function SavePrint() {
        document.execCommand('print', false, null);
    }
```

The problem is that when we then navigate back through the site all of the contents has shrunk. I believe that IE is resizing everything to print fit. I am trying to work out a decent way to prevent this from happening. Can anyone advise on good approach.

Comment: resizing where? printed document or in the browser? Reason you do not call window.print()

Comment: I can call window.print(), it does the same. Essentially the whole site becomes a different size. I'm trying to stop this IE behaviour.

Comment: I am using Version 11, I think it's across all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE does this to "help". One solution is to instruct your users to uncheck Enable Shrink-to-Fit on the Page Setup dialog.